# Django Class Based View (update view)

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I want to update the labels of images using Update view(Class-based-views). I can update labels of one image at a time but I would like to update labels of multiple images at once.

Will passing a list of Image IDs to update view work? (How to pass a list of ids in Url pattern?)
Can someone please help me with the methods I should be using in update view??

Here is my models.py

```
class DataFile(models.Model):
  
  image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
  label = models.CharField( null=True, blank=True )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you want is to use the `getlist` method to get multiple data

If you have a form like

```
<form ...>
    <input name="label" value="A image">
    <input name="label" value="B image">
</form>
```

then, from your views you can use the request to access the list of labels

`request.<POST or GET>.getlist('name')` will return ["A image", "B image"]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I use the same form to delete multiple images at a time? If yes then how do I redirect the form to relabelling or delete functions in views using URL pattern?

Comment: it worked!. Thanks Luismontanaresm.
Soln: I just wrapped all the images in a form with different submit buttons